# Vowels Context free grammar definition YACC

Tags: yacc, lex, context-free-grammar

I am writing a YACC program defining the CFG for vowels in the given string, My code attempt is as follows

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%union{
  char c;   
}

%token <c> VOW

%%
cha :   'a' { printf("a\n"); } 
    | 'e' {printf("e\n");}
    | 'i' {printf("i\n");}
    | 'o' {printf("o\n");}
    | 'u' {printf("u\n");}
    ;
%%

int main(void) {return yyparse();}
int yylex(void) {return getchar();}
void yyerror(char *s) {fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",s);}
```

Is this a correct definition of a CFG for vowels

Comment: It depends what exactly you mean. You said 'vowels', and this is a CFG for a language where a legal sentence consists of a single vowel, but if I was implementing this I would want a more precise definition.

Comment: I'm trying to parse a string through this and search for the vowels

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what a CFG is -- CFGs match entire strings, not parts of a string, and describe a langauge of strings.  Do you want "all strings that contain vowels" or "all strings that contain only vowels"?  Both of those are much easier to do with a simple regular expression rather than yacc.

Comment: You also seem to be using entirely the wrong tool for the job. You could easily accomplish that objective entirely within *flex(1)*, and you can't really do it at all with *yacc(1)*, at least not well, and you don't need most of what *yacc(1)* can do for you. You're using a hammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a context-free grammar for your problem, only a regular expresion. You're using the wrong tool for the job. It is three lines in *flex(1)*:

```
%%
[aeiou] printf("%\n", yytext);
.|\n ;
```